# How can I write an entire c++ glut program as a function that can be called in another program?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, freeglut

I want call below code as function in my OpenGL program.My questions are:

1. Is it possible to call glutIdleFunc() outside of the main() ?
2. Can I call below code as a function in my main program as a switch case function?

   ```
   #include<GL/glut.h>
   #include<math.h>
   #include<stdio.h>
   int bzco[4][2]={{0,0},{49,201},{201,99},{320,300}},c[4],n=3;
   int s1x,s1y,s2x,s2y;
   void bezierCoefficients(int n,int *c)
   {
       int k,i;
       for(k=0;k<=n;k++)
       {
           c[k]=1;

           for(i=n;i>=k+1;i--)
               c[k]*=i;

           for(i=n-k;i>=2;i--)
               c[k]/=i;
       }
   }

   void display(void)
   {
   int k;

   float x,y,u,blend;

       glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
       // To draw points
       glColor3f(0.0,1.0,0.0);
       glPointSize(3);
           glBegin(GL_POINTS);
           glVertex2f(80, 34);
           glVertex2f(85, 24);
           glVertex2f(78, 24);
           glVertex2f(46, 35);
           glVertex2f(67, 47);
           glVertex2f(85, 26);
           glVertex2f(78, 68);
           glVertex2f(86, 56);
           glVertex2f(82, 54);
           glVertex2f(56, 69);
       glEnd();
       glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
       glPointSize(3);
       glBegin(GL_POINTS);
           glVertex2f(34, 38);
           glVertex2f(46, 35);
           glVertex2f(56, 69);
           glVertex2f(43, 47);

       glEnd();
       glColor3f(0.0,0.0,1.0);
       glLineWidth(3.0);
       glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);

       for(u=0;u<1.0;u+=0.001)
       {x=0;y=0;
           for(k=0;k<4;k++)
           {
               blend=c[k]*pow(u,k)*pow(1-u,n-k);
               x+=bzco[k][0]*blend;
               y+=bzco[k][1]*blend;
           }
           glVertex2f(x,y);

       }
       glEnd();
       glFlush();
       glutSwapBuffers();
   }
   void myinit()
   {
       glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
       glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
       glPointSize(5.0);
       gluOrtho2D(0.0,320.0,0.0,300.0);
   }
   void motion(void)
   {
       bzco[1][0]+=s1x;
       bzco[1][1]+=s1y;
       bzco[2][0]+=s2x;
       bzco[2][1]+=s2y;
       if(bzco[1][0]<0||bzco[1][0]>320)
       {
           s1x=-s1x;
       }
       if(bzco[1][1]<0||bzco[1][1]>300)
       {
           s1y=-s1y;
       }
       if(bzco[2][0]<0||bzco[2][0]>320)
       {
           s2x=-s2x;
       }
       if(bzco[2][1]<0||bzco[2][1]>300)
       {
           s2y=-s2y;
       }
       glutPostRedisplay();
   }
   ```

Main function :

```
    int main(int argc, char ** argv)
    {
        glutInit(&argc,argv);
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGB);
        glutInitWindowSize(320,300);
        glutCreateWindow("Logistic Function");
        glutDisplayFunc(display);
        glutDisplayFunc(display);
        glutIdleFunc(motion);
        myinit();
        bezierCoefficients(n,c);
        s1x=-1;s1y=-1;s2x=-1;s2y=1;
        glutMainLoop();
        return 0;
    }
```

In my main program I am using switch cases in display() fuction, in that I have to call above code.

Comment: In C++, any function other than `main()` may be called from any other function.   It is, of course, necessary to ensure functions are called correctly (with expected arguments, valid values of those arguments, etc).   There is also nothing preventing `main()` from being edited, renamed, and called from other code.

Comment: This question summarises to: "How do I write a C++ library either static or dynamic?"  As such this is too broad.  Please narrow your question.

Comment: @Peter I can't use two main () function.

Comment: What platform are you targeting? There's no standards for static/dynamic linking so you will have to write platform specific code to do so

Comment: @Asesh I am working in Linux platform

Comment: @introvertkernel - there is noting preventing you from editing the source of `main()` to RENAME the `main()` function.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a library, put your functions in it, and export them to be able to access them from another application. To export functions in visual c++ compiler you must declare them like the following:

```
void __declspec(dllexport) motion();
```

Later you must import it in your application to be able using it like this:

```
void __declspec(dllimport) motion();
```

You can declare some macro like MY_API like this:

```
#if (defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN32_WCE)) && defined(MY_LIB_DYNAMIC)
#   if defined(MY_LIB_SOURCE)
#       define MY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#   else
#       define MY_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#   endif
#endif

#if !defined(MY_API)
#   if defined (__GNUC__) && (__GNUC__ >= 4)
#       define MY_API __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#   else
#       define MY_API
#   endif
#endif
```

And then declare your functions like this:

```
void MY_API motion();
```

It allows you to use the same code to create either static or dynamic library in visual c++ and gcc compilers. If you want to statically compile your library, you can compile it and your application without any pre-processor definitions. If you want to dynamically compile your library, you can add MY_LIB_DYNAMIC and MY_LIB_SOURCE as pre-processor definitions to your compiler but compile your application just with MY_LIB_DYNAMIC as a pre-processor definition.